# Create function that returns repeated characters in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a function that takes a string as input and returns a string that consists of all characters occurring in the input string at least `n` times, in the order they occur.

For example, `repeat("cchatlpcat", 2)` would return the string `cat`.

Comment: Hi Joey, can you please edit the post and make it more clear, in terms of what you are needing?

Answer (score 2):

```
def repeat(string, n):
  result=''
  for x in string:
    if string.count(x) >= n and x not in result:
      result += x
  return result

result1 = repeat("cchatlpcat", 2)
result2 = repeat("ccchatalpcatt", 3)
```

Both the above test strings will return the string `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `str` is an iterable, you can easily use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this. First set it up:

```
my_count = Counter("cchatlpcat")
```

Then get all characters with more than 2 hits and join them into a `str` again:

```
''.join(e for e in my_count if my_count[e] >= 2)
```

The join operates over a generator where `e` is each key (item) known to `my_counter`. `my_count[e]` is a value of how many times item `e` has appeared in the iterable we have setup the `Counter` with.

Or written in a `repeat` function:

```
from collections import Counter
def repeat(string, min_count):
    my_count = Counter(string)
    return ''.join(e for e in my_count if my_count[e] >= min_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repeat(string, n):
  return ''.join(set(filter(lambda letter: string.count(letter) >= n, string)))
```

It will return 'act' (sorted string) because of set() function

```
def repeat(string, n):
  res = ''
  filtered = filter(lambda letter: string.count(letter) >= n, string)
  for i in filtered:
    if i not in res:
      res += i
  return res
```

it will return 'cat'